# change date format for timedatectl ubuntu

Tags: systemd, time, date

How to change date format for the command

```
timedatectl
```

I'm getting results like YYYY-MM-DD I need DD-MM-YYYY

```
Local time: Mon 2022-05-16 14:41:06 IST
Universal time: Mon 2022-05-16 09:11:06 UTC                 
RTC time: Mon 2022-05-16 09:11:06
```

Please suggest.